# How to add laravel pagination with custom array?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5.1

I want to add pagination in my custom laravel query.
Here is my code.

```
$jobseekers = Jobseeker::where('employer_id', Auth::employer()->get()->id)->get()->toArray();

$jobs = Job::select('id')->where('employer_id', (Auth::employer()->get()->id))->get()->toArray();

$apps = DB::table('applications')
            ->leftJoin('jobseekers', 'applications.jobseeker_id', '=', 'jobseekers.id')
            ->groupby('jobseekers.id')
            ->whereIn('applications.job_id', $jobs)
            ->get();

     $apps_array = array();
     for ($i = 0; $i < count($apps); $i++) {
        $apps_array[$i] = (array) $apps[$i];
     }

     $jobseeker = array_merge($jobseekers, $apps_array);

     return view('frontend.manageCV', compact('jobseeker', 'assignJS'));
```

Comment: Were is the $apps variable coming from.

Comment: i  just define at 3rd line

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let see how it goes

```
// I have changed the get to paginate
$jobseekers = Jobseeker::where('employer_id', Auth::employer()->get()->id)->paginate();

$jobs = Job::select('id')->where('employer_id', (Auth::employer()->get()->id))->get()->toArray();

$apps = DB::table('applications')
        ->leftJoin('jobseekers', 'applications.jobseeker_id', '=', 'jobseekers.id')
        ->groupby('jobseekers.id')
        ->whereIn('applications.job_id', $jobs)
        ->get();

 $apps_array = array();
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($apps); $i++) {
    $apps_array[$i] = (array) $apps[$i];
 }

 // I am merging to the $jobseekers->data in $jobseekers array
 $jobseekers->data = (object)array_merge((array)$jobseekers->data, $apps_array);

 return view('frontend.manageCV', compact('jobseekers', 'assignJS'));
```

Comment: but it will give error in template : Call to a member function render() on a non-object

Comment: If you are using it in a view then you dont have to call the toArray on the Collection. Updating my answer.

Comment: Also in total it count only $jobseekers data. Cant consider $apps_array record

Comment: Wish i can see your models and the final results after the merging.

Comment: its give error at merge line : Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$data

Comment: change it to $jobseekers['data'] and let see what happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105887/discussion-between-vipul-sorathiya-and-oseintow).